# CodeIgniter - URL routing for more cases

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, codeigniter-3

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
https://www.example.com/properties
https://www.example.com/properties/properties-in-newyork
https://www.example.com/properties/properties-in-DC/property-for-rent
https://www.example.com/properties/all-cities/property-for-rent
https://www.example.com/properties/all-cities/property-for-sale
```

All above is for search. Now I want to get details page like:

```
https://www.example.com/properties/2br-apartment-for-sale-100
```

I want to differentiate between search and details page links. Here is what I tried:

```
$route['properties/index']  = 'properties';
$route['properties(/:any)'] = 'properties/property_details$1';
```

How can I differential which URL is for properties/property_details function and which URL is for properties/index function?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE7SU.png)

Comment: try with `$route['properties/(:any)'] = 'properties/$1';$route['properties/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'properties/$1/$2';`

Comment: $route['properties(/:any)'] is using for property_details function. i need to take care of property_details function also

Answer (score 1):

*Set your `route.php` like this :*

```
$route['properties/index']  = 'properties';
$route['properties'] = 'properties/property_details';
$route['properties/(:any)'] = 'properties/property_details/$1';
```

Access url :

this direct you index method

```
https://www.example.com/properties/index
```

this will direct you property_details method

```
https://www.example.com/properties/
```

Controller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Properties extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construtct()
    {
        parent::__construtct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'index';
    }

    public function property_details($component = NULL)
    {
      echo 'property_details';
      echo $component;
    }

}
```

Comment: how to handle properties/property_details requests?https://www.example.com/properties/2br-apartment-for-sale-100

Comment: do i need to add this line also?$route['properties(/:any)'] = 'properties/property_details$1';...in your code there is no discussion of property_details method

Comment: `$1` will handle your request for `property_details` and `$2` will for  `2br-apartment-for-sale-100`

Comment: there are two functions/methods (index and property_details) in my controller(properties). i doubt all your code will only use index function and will not use property_details function. these are two different functions

Comment: I want to hide property_details from url and make it user friendly

Comment: http://localhost/ci/index.php/properties/properties_in_lhr..not working, please check my post, i added image..your code not working for all cases

Comment: ok updated my answer pls check and let me know its working or not

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, according to your explanation with differentiating the routes, the problem you are having is, it always running the route for `index` despite of what your URL having after `properties`.

You may try it by changing the order of the routes like this;

```
$route['properties(/:any)'] = 'properties/property_details/$1';
$route['properties/index']  = 'properties';
```

It always works according to the order of the routes you have placed. If there are acceptable parameters, for the program, `properties/index` is also something similar to `properties(/:any)`. So, to differentiate between these two, we have to change the order of the routes like this.